# Can I upgrade GLIBC 2.15 to GLIBC 2.17 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, glibc

I'm trying to compile a program on Ubuntu 12.04, and I got the following error message:

```
make: lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by make)
```

My Ubuntu is currently using GLIBC_2.15, and I know that I can upgrade my GLIBC by upgrading my Ubuntu to a higher version.

My question is: is there a way to only upgrade GLIBC to 2.17 while not upgrading my Ubuntu OS?

(I have tried

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

they didn't work.

I also manually downloaded a lib6_2.17-xxx.deb and install using dpkg -i, but this failed because some dependency issues.
)